# I can’t understand the meaning of this sentence

Tags: past-tense

“It seemed like weeks went by before you finally asked for my number”

Is that mean he asked numbers quickly or few weeks later?

Excerpt From
Thirteen Reasons Why
Jay Asher
This material may be protected by copyright.

Answer (score 1):

I think the person from whom the number was to be asked was eagerly waiting for the other person to ask for his number.

So even if, the person may have asked the number not too later, it seemed to the other person as if he had waited for a long time.

So the word 'seemed like' has been used.

Answer (score 1):

The author is referring to the time you asked for his number, and the fact that the author thinks you (seemingly) waited a long time before asking.  The delay is the key sentiment here so maybe he/she was hoping you had asked sooner.